# How to place an object in a struct

Tags: c++, class, object, struct

Normal way to make a new object:

`std::string date1 = "10/1/2010"; Date d1(stringToChar(date1);`

But I can't figure out how to use that in a struct. The struct:

```
struct RecPayments
{
    std::string name;
    Date datemake();
    float cost;
};
```

Trying to use it like this:

```
void addRecurring()
{
    //New recurring payment
    RecPayments * newPaymentItem = new RecPayments;

    //Set recurring payment properties
    newPaymentItem->name = "Test Payment";
    newPaymentItem->datemake(stringToChar("4/12/2011"));
    newPaymentItem->cost = 5;
}
```

Error received:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘RecPayments::datemake(const char*)`

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: C and C++ are not the same thing.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes the Date class I am using is writtin in C so since I'm mixing both C and C++ I thought it would be appropriate to add both as a tag..

Comment: @natili, no the class is _not_ a C struct, since its members contain non-trivial constructors, and a function.

Comment: Hmm.. the more pointers you create on heap the more headache you have later to manage them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The braces `()` in your `Date datemake();` are confusing the compiler.

Just remove them.

If you want to explicitly create the `Date` object inside `addRecurring()` with non default c'tor then make it a pointer and create it..

```
struct RecPayments
{
    std::string name;
    Date* date;
    float cost;
};

void addRecurring()
{
    //New recurring payment
    RecPayments * newPaymentItem = new RecPayments;

    //Set recurring payment properties
    newPaymentItem->name = "Test Payment";
    newPaymentItem->date = new Date(stringToChar("4/12/2011"));
    newPaymentItem->cost = 5;
}
```

obviously as you use `new`, you'll now need `delete` somewhere as well.. or use smart pointers..

Comment: That's not an answer to the question, though.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the compiler is right. The way you've used the struct has given you (in effect) a class. You declared a function `RecPayments::datemake()` but never defined it anywhere. What's more, you didn't even call this version of the function you created--you sent with it an argument that it didn't expect.

You need to remove the `()` in the datemake variable you've declared, or make a full function out of it. I'm not sure from the question which one you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
std::string date1 = "10/1/2010";
```

is an initialization using an overloaded operator `=`.

This

```
Date d1(stringToChar(date1);
```

is an initialization by a constructor.

In

```
struct RecPayments
{
    std::string name;
    Date datemake();
    float cost;
};
```

`Date datemake();` is a declaration of a function that returns `Date`, not a member field of type `Date`. So you need to remove those braces.

Also

```
newPaymentItem->datemake(stringToChar("4/12/2011"));
```

is a function call, but all you really want to do is an assignment. So it should be changed to `newPaymentItem->datemake = stringToChar("4/12/2011");` The latter implies that your `Date` class has an appropriate overloading of operator `=`. If it was not overloaded, then you might say `newPaymentItem->datemake = Date(stringToChar("4/12/2011");)` in this case automatically overloaded operator `=` will be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date datemake();
```

This is defined as a function that takes no argument. When you call it as

```
newPaymentItem->datemake(stringToChar("4/12/2011"));
```

you are passing string from stringToChar() to you function datemake().

What you can do is first make an Date variable in your structure as

```
Date date;
```

and then assign it value as

```
newPaymentItem->date = stringToChar("4/12/2011");
```

Comment: That works only if there is a copy c'tor / assignment operator available for `Date` type.

Comment: @thekashayap sir i dont know about the definition of Date class. I just assumed it has a copy constructor. I dont have much knowledge about MFC classes(in case Date is a MFC)